# Spring util properties in app-context xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am describing properties file in `app-context.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

    <task:annotation-driven />


    <util:properties id="properties" location="file:/opt/vortal/VortalDataProvider/config/votral.properties"></util:properties>

</beans>
```

in any java file I am able to access this file through:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("properties")
private Properties properties;
```

However when I try to access properties in `camel-context.xml`

like:

```
<cxf:rsClient id="vortalEndpoint" address="${endpointUrl}" 
     serviceClass="pl.test.dataprovider.Processor"
     skipFaultLogging="false"/>
```

value of bean `vortalEndpoint` is literally `${endpointUrl}` - value from poperties is not read.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<util:properties>
```

initialized an instance of `java.util.Properties` class, check out the [Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html). This is not the proper way to load your properties, if you are doing it in xml, you can use

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties" />
```

Then you can access your properties easily with

```
 @Value("${whatever}")
 private String myValue
```